# AngularJs - Set div and textarea height by Id. both have same Id

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have same Id for html div and textarea which is auto generated by some plugin.

Already searched in internet but most of results are like angular tag based as given code

```
<div id="wrapper" set-height>
```

like this

```
.directive('setHeight', function($window){
```

My need is just want to set height for them by using Angularjs.
div should be like

```
<div id="wrapper">
```

Comment: _"both have the same id"_... That's your problem right there

Comment: @AlonEitan These are dynamic element generated by textangualar

Comment: The problem is that you have multiple elements with the same ID, while the whole purpose of the `id` attribute is to be unique in the DOM, if you have multiple ids, than you should use the `class` attribute to select them instead - I don't know if that is actually the reason, but I am sure that it's invalid use of the `id` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your `div` and `textarea` have the following code,

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
<textarea rows="10" col="5" id="wrapper"></textarea>
```

To provide separate css styling to them you can do something like this in the css file:

```
div#wrapper {
   background-color: yellow;
}

textarea#wrapper {
   background-color: green;
}
```

So, if you want to do the same using AngularJs, you can use the `document.querySelector()` function to get the element and use the `myEle.css()` method to change the style like this:

```
var divWrapperElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('div#wrapper'));
divWrapperElement.css('background-color','yellow');
var textareaWrapperElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('textarea#wrapper'));
textareaWrapperElement.css('background-color','green');
```

Hope this helps..!!

Comment: I tried the code but I am not able to see any change on pressing the `resize` button. But try using the `div` without the id. I mean, instead of writing `'div#'+Id`, try only `'div'`.